# Background Image height- should not specify

Tags: html, css

I think my question is very basic, for some reason my backgound image isnt repeating vertically. Can anyone see why?

```
body
{
background: url("/images/blueback5.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 62.5%;
}
#global-wrap 
{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
width: 880px;
}
#global-inner 
{
background: url("/images/main_bg.gif") repeat-y scroll 0 0 #E4EAEF;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
/*overflow: visible;*/
text-align: left;
width: 880px;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't specify an explicit height. The height should be determined automatically by the content inside. Also, what's your actual question?

Comment: Im trying to implement that image with different heights from 800px to 1100px.

Comment: So what goes wrong? Does your background image not extend down far enough when you go past `800px` height?

Comment: I havent tested that. I assumed that because the image itself is 880px, that it wouldnt stretch to 1100px.  Your saying that I shouldnt specify the height within the CSS, would this also apply for the body attribute w/in the CSS?  I updated the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, here goes this slightly inane answer:

The idea is make your image (`/images/main_bg.gif`) be `880px` wide, and `1px` high (or `24px`, whatever number).

You have `repeat-y` inside your `background` declaration, which means the image will repeat endlessly downwards as the background of `#global-inner`.

The height of `#global-inner`, and so the height of the background image, will be determined by the height of the content inside this element.

If you want to ensure that the height is at least `800px`, you can use `min-height: 800px`, instead.

Comment: Thanks Thirty, that makes alot of sense now.

Comment: No problem. I see you added your `body` CSS to your question, do you need any explanation about that?

Comment: Maybe? What should I change there?

Comment: Well, to answer your question `"Should the height be specified?"` - no, you probably should not specify an explicit height on the `body`. You simply don't need to, because the height will be automatically worked out based on the height of the stuff inside the `body`.

Comment: Thanks for clueing me in on that!

Answer (score 1):

Image height is not `880px` instead its width is `880px`. Height is only `20px`.

Below is the Original Image its using for background.

[image: The background Image]

Its simply using `repeat-y` in CSS to extend it to whatever size the `#content` `Div` has.

Also its simply overlaying the background image with 4 separate corner divs with corner background images.

Below is the Template of what has been done there .

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="top-left-coner'>
    </div> 
    ...
    <div id="top-right-coner'>
    </div>
    ...
    <div id="bottom-left-coner'>
    </div>
    ...
    <div id="bottom-left-coner'>
    </div>
    ...
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then assign background images with CSS.

Comment: What a horrible way they chose to make rounded corners :)

Comment: I kind of did the same thing ;-( Im obviously going to have to change that also because I have the absolute margin height set, and this is going to change depending upon the height of the background image I described. I updated that code as well.  If you have a better solution for this also, Im all ears.

Comment: yeah i usually go with CSS3 or simply have it in three `div`s with top and bottom divs having a single image containing corners for both side.. since in this case we know that width of page is fixed 880px.  :)

Comment: ok so your saying have a top and bottom div to include the left and right corners?

Comment: You don't need left and right corners..because page width is fixed.. if you have set your Width to 100% or Auto then you may need to do that but if your page is Fixed width then you simply have a single Image with both left and Right Curves and Middle part

Comment: So this would cover the bottom left and right corners as well. A single image with all 4 rounded corners, with an image height of 20px or similar?  the width is fixed at 880px.

Comment: Would having the corners associated with a single image, then distort those corners when the height of the image changes?

Comment: you mentioned that instead of having 4 seperate images for the corners, just to have a single image to include the 4 corners, since the width remains at 880px.  My question is, would the bottom corners become distorted as the height of the image changes?

Comment: no no..i said total of three images.. one for top with corners one repeated for middle and one for bottom with corners..BTW why dont you try CSS3 instead

Comment: So then my question becomes, how would I change the position of the bottom image that has the lower corners?  Because this positon will change depending upon the height.  www.williamsprofessionalpainting.com uses float for the position, I posted that code above.                                           For CSS3, I cant really go to all that trouble to change everything, because I have to first finish this site. Maybe Phase 2 for CSS3!

Comment: you don't need to... it will automatically go below the content area...Also i can see in you CSS that you are specifying height tobe 1000px.. DON'T do that.. leave it to do it automatically.. then you won't have to worry about positioning...

Comment: You can see in their code they have the margin-top: -8px;   Do I need to implement that?

Comment: dont copy paste every thing.. they have put that to fix things and bounding box.. you should just take the idea and write your own CSS.. use some IDE like DreamWeaver or ExpressionBlend.. and these comments are not ment for chatting.. come to [facebook](http://facebook.com/samajshekhar) for that

Comment: My image isnt repeating vertically, I will post what I have

Comment: @Shekhar since this seems to be a different problem, I have posted a new question regarding this issue