# Background Image wont repeat vertically beyond the ContentPlaceHolder and Child Page

Tags: html, css

I think this should be an easy problem to solve, however its turned into something I cant solve.

For whatever reason my background image (main_bg.gif) specified within global-inner and used within the MasterPage will only repeat vertically for the Content Page within the MasterPage, if in fact that ContentPage contains no other div.

For the rest of the div's within the MasterPage such as bottom-wrap, the image (main_bg.gif) will not stretch down for it.  It only repeats for whats contained within the Content Page.

Here is top-feature used within the CSS for the Child Page, which doesnt enable the image within global-inner to repeat:

```
#top-feature 
{
height:330px;
width: 848px;
margin: 12px 0 0 16px;
/*background: #E4EAEF;*/
background: orange;
/*padding: 10px 0 0 10px;*/
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
}
```

Here is the CSS used within the MasterPage:

```
body
{
background-color: #9EB0C8;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 62.5%;
}    

#global-wrap 
{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
width: 880px;
overflow: hidden;
}    

#global-inner 
{
background: url("/images/main_bg.gif") repeat-y scroll 0 0 #E4EAEF;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
width: 880px;
}
```

Here is the HTML w/in the MasterPage.  Again anything beyond the ContentPlaceHolder ie bottom-wrap, will not be included in that image (main_bg.gif) :

```
<div id="global-wrap">
    <div id="global-inner">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        <div id="bottom-wrap">
            <div id="copyright">
                Copyright © 2011 by DaVinci's Painting, Inc.
                <br />
                2111 Jefferson Davis Hwy, Arlington, Virginia
                <br />
                Call Direct: 202-460-1754
                <br />
                Site Development by <a target="blank" href="http://www.websitedeveloper.com">WebSiteDeveloper.com</a>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom-logos">
            </div>
            <div id="sociales">
                <span class="st_twitter_large" displaytext="Tweet"></span><span class="st_facebook_large"
                    displaytext="Facebook"></span><span class="st_ybuzz_large" displaytext="Yahoo! Buzz">
                    </span><span class="st_gbuzz_large" displaytext="Google Buzz"></span><span class="st_email_large"
                        displaytext="Email"></span><span class="st_sharethis_large" displaytext="ShareThis">
                        </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125470/background-image-isnt-repeating-vertically) and has been answered before.

Comment: Im sorry this is a different question, and this wasnt answered before, but thanks for reading my previous post and your help! Obviously I wouldnt have posted this if I had the answer right?

Comment: Do you have elements inside `#global-inner` which have a `float` property? Such as `float: left`?

Comment: @Paul, Can you provide us some of the HTML that goes with the styles? On initial view it looks like you are not clearing the floats and so the background is not showing up.

Comment: Yes you can FireBug it- I just uploaded this- www.davincispainting.com    Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `overflow:hidden;` to your `#global-inner` style, this will solve the problem of the floats not being cleared and display the background image.

Also, it's probably not the best idea or practice using separate empty DIVs for the left and right corners. Have you looked into ***CSS3*** rounded corners as an alternative to using images?

**For example:**

```
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;

    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: @Dan That did solve the problem.  I havent looked into the CSS3.  Could you tell me, how much of the current CSS I would need to change to comply with CSS3?  Also, exactly where would I put that code you illustrated?

Comment: 2nd Question for what appears to be the same issue.  The image w/in the Body (blueback5.jpg) only stretches down so far.  As you can see there is whitespace at the bottom.  Should this not stretch all the way down?

Comment: @Paul, to implement the rounded corners on that container, you would need to add the above style to the #global-inner. As for using css3, I'm not sure how much of your css you would need to update as I haven't taken an in-depth look at your stylesheet. You don't necessarily need to override your styleheet, these are just things that will reduce your work load. I would do a google search on css3 and have a read up about some of the cools things you can now do.

Comment: Its complaining that the following isnt a known CSS element: border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;   Im going to have to change something regarding the bottom corners because whenever I add-- margin-top: -8px; or even if I dont specify a margin at all,, the vertical repeat no longer works.

Comment: @Paul, as for the background not extending to the bottom of the page, I'm not sure. Are you using an image as the background? If so, why not just use background-color: to declare the flat background colour in the body property.

Comment: @What's complaining? CSS3 is new and supported by most modern browsers. I think IE is the only one that has real issues with CSS3 rounded corners. The -moz-border... and -webkit-border... are hacks until it is fully supported as standard, then they will be ignored and the border-top-radius.... will only be recognised. I suggest taking some time out and having a browse on the internet about these new css features. Best of luck.

Comment: Yes I was using an image for the background, but changed this to background-color which solved that issue.

Comment: The compiler is complaining in VisualStudio 2010, it seems my only options are:  CSS 1.0, 2.0, 2.1

Comment: If I totally eliminate the bottom corners, the main_bg.gif no longer vertically repeats. Any idea why?

Comment: Not to sure about VisualStudio 2010, sorry mate. Might be another question for Stack Overflow - How to use CSS3 elements and styling in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: yes but thats totally secondary.  The issue that I thought we solved, isnt really solved.  I eliminated the two divs: .bottomleft and .bottomright, which brings me back to my original problem with the vertical repeat not functioning

Comment: I don't understand Paul. If a child DIV is floated within a parent DIV that has overflow:hidden and zoom:1 (for IE6&7) assigned to its style, then it will be cleared. I think you need to look into your HTML and CSS styling.

Comment: @Dan I've been looking at this for 2 days- I would love to solve this myself. I have it all posted, what do you see?  I dont have anything regarding zoom.

Comment: Paul, the zoom:1 attribute is something you add to the parent element that contains floated children. It is merely used to get IE6 and IE7 to behave in the way that other browsers should. This shouldn't affect what we have been talking about. If you are happy to use separate DIVS that contain the corners, then do so. All I was saying is that it isn't considered to be best practice.

Comment: Well I would be happy to hear about a better solution that doesnt include those seperate Divs.  It seems that the solution you mentioned earlier with CSS3 would be the best, but I dont have that option.  Sorry that I dont know so much about CSS

Comment: It's all good Paul, good to see you having a crack at CSS. I'll be able to help you out with another option in a short while (have got plenty of work on ATM). So if you don't mind waiting, I'll post some info up for you when I get a chance.

Comment: @Paul: What are you stuck with here? Do you want to know the best way to do rounded corners?

Comment: Yes!  The issue Im having is with the Content Page. I recreated the site and eliminated everything within Default.aspx, except for text, and the image within the MasterPage vertically repeats fine.  So really its two issues.  Rounded corners, and the problem Im having with the vertical strech of that background image.  So yea if you have any idea for a better way to deal with those rounded corners that would be great.

Comment: @thirtydot Im going to post a new question regarding those rounded corners, because its something not related to this problem.

Comment: If you're a Jquery UI user (which I highly recommend for a number of different reasons) rounded corners are as simple as adding the class ui-corner-all

Answer (score 0):

The Child Div's of a Parent Div containing an Image that needs to be vertically repeated, cannot have their position set to absolute.

In my example of the MasterPage: bottom-wrap had its position set to absolute.  When this was changed to position:relative, the parent image within global-inner vertically stretched all the way down to include the bottom-wrap div.